# Change the space between the ticklabels and axes (same for ticklabel and ylabel or xlabel) in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How do I change space between the ticklabels and the axes (s2), same for ticklabel and ylabel or xlabel (s1, s3) in matlab (I using matlab 2015b).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`xlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html) and [`ylabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylabel.html) you will see that you can specify the optional output argument to return a `Text` object, which you can use to access and modify the [properties of the label](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html) after it has been created.

Of interest here is the `'Position'` property of the label, which is an `[x y z*]` position vector (z is optional). For example:

```
plot(1:10);
xl = xlabel('An X Label');
yl = ylabel('A Y Label');
```

Generates the following:

[image: before]

Which we can then adjust:

```
xl.Position(2) = 0.15;  % Shift x label down
yl.Position(1) = 0.20;  % Shift y label left
```

[image: after]

As far as I can remember I don't believe there's a simple way to adjust the tick offset.

Answer (score 1):

For the axes labels, do what [@excaza wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45091046/2627163). For the axis tick labels you can use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to create new tick labels in the offset you want:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 2*x;
plot(x,y)
ax = gca;
S2 = 2; % this is S2 from your qusetion, in your data units
% make a vector of vertical position after the offset:
offset = repmat(ax.YTick(1)-S2,1,numel(ax.XTick));
% create new lables:
text(ax.XTick,offset,ax.XTickLabel,'HorizontalAlign','center')
% remove the original ones:
ax.XTickLabel = [];
```

the result:

[image]